# Does a source exist for high-resolution PAL (not NTSC) video game cover scans?

Tags: gaming, game-cartridge, data-preservation

I have created a database table of PAL games that I once owned for these platforms: Amiga, Game Boy, Game Boy Advance, Game Boy Color, Game Gear, Mega Drive, Master System, Nintendo 64, Nintendo Entertainment System, Super Nintendo Entertainment System, Atari XE Video Game System, Saturn, PlayStation, Atari Jaguar, PC (MS-DOS), PC (Windows), PlayStation 2, Nintendo Wii, Nintendo DS, GameCube, PlayStation Portable, Xbox and Nintendo Wii U.

Over a number of months, I've extensively attempted to find one or more high-quality website/archive for consistent box art scans from the PAL region. My conclusions are:

1. There are *tons* of box art scan projects/websites and by now, I probably know of all of the ones that can be found with search engines.
2. All are very incomplete, and very NTSC-focused. When PAL scans exist, they are frequently in German instead of English (or another European language). With few exceptions, I never had any German-language PAL boxes.
3. The Github project(s) trying to standardize box art images are extremely low-resolution (and NTSC only). I'm trying to obtain high-resolution scans only.
4. A few of them make "artistic interpretations" of the box scans, for example including elements from the whole package into one single image. I'm only looking for the original front covers.
5. Using DuckDuckGo Image Search, with a query such as "Donkey Kong SNES PAL box art", size set to "wallpaper only", I am *sometimes* able to manually pick out a decent image for certain games. However, this is *far* from guaranteed, and the sizes/scan qualities vary, so there is no consistency, forcing me to do a lot of unnecessary work besides the whole process of picking these out in the first place.

Since I don't actually have the boxes anymore, since I'm an idiot who either sold or even *threw them away* long ago, I cannot fire up the old scanner and simply scan them all myself.

Is this simply a hopeless task? Should I just give up and conclude that this is not going to happen until some distant point in the future when these games have turned into actual antiques and somebody puts in the work professionally?

Comment: Sounds pretty similar to [this question](/q/16254), and we closed that one as off-topic, so…

Comment: I think this question contains the answer: No. It seems you have done a quite big search of known (and unknown to me) sources and come up with nothing.

Comment: might be on topic in https://gaming.stackexchange.com check the rules. Be aware that you are asking for copies of copyrighted material.